# Htaccess redirect issue with query string param not being

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I recently changed my hosting. The old server had php 5.3 and the newer has php 5.6. This change in host is one step towards making my website compatible with php 7.

However I have come across an issue with htaccess redirect.

My htaccess file looks like below

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^company/([0-9]+)/?$    company.php?company_id=$1 [L]
```

So when I go to page with url `mydomain.com/admin/company/92`

I don't seem to get the redirected URL as required i.e. `mydomain.com/admin/company.php?company_id=92`

This is some of the output from printing `$_SERVER`

```
    [REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URL] => /admin/company/92/
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /htdocs/myproj/admin/company.php
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /admin/company.php/92/
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REQUEST_URI] => /admin/company/92/
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /admin/company.php
    [STATUS] => 200
    [ORIG_PATH_INFO] => /92/
    [ORIG_PATH_TRANSLATED] => /htdocs/myproj/admin/company.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /admin/company.php
    [argv] => Array
        (
        )

    [argc] => 0
)
```

I have got php 5.3 on my local and the same code works fine on my local. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: in `^company` the `^` sticks it to the start of the string. So anything before `company` will make it fail to match. You could change it to `RewriteRule /company/([0-9]+)/?$   /company.php?company_id=$1 [L]` for example

Comment: I tried removing ^ but I still don't get anything in QUERY_STRING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely effect of option `MultiViews` turned on by default new host.

You can turn it off like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteRule ^company/([0-9]+)/?$ company.php?company_id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.

Comment: Hi Anubhav, I changed as above but still don't get any value in the [QUERY_STRING] => .... On my local with php 5.3 I can still see [QUERY_STRING] => company_id=92

Comment: You are right. It doesn't seem to be enabled at directory level!!!! Thank you. I will call my hosting company now and get it enabled. I think most likely that is the issue. How silly of me of not to think to check that first.

Comment: My bad - htaccess is enabled but I was making changes in a wrong file. I made above changes in the correct file now and I get 500 internal server error (i.e. after adding -mulitviews and [L, NC, QSA]. Please advise. Thank you so much for you time.

Comment: Are there any other changes you can think of? I have tried speaking to hosting customer care but i haven't had any luck. Thank you.

Comment: I put -MultiViews again and with [L, NC, QSA, R] - when I go to mydomain.com/admin/company/92 it redirects me to mydomain.com/kunden/homepages/121/46545/htdocs/mypoject/admin/company.php?company_id=92 .... so its getting there just need to ensure that redirect only goes to mydomain/admin/company.php?company_id=92

Comment: The above is already in /admin/.htaccess ... I put `-Multiviews` in the base folder too now i.e. .htacess > Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews ... but it still redirects to the above url with all the document root directories.

Comment: I tried in a different browser - it redirects `mydomain/admin/company/92` to `mydomain/kunden/homepages/121/46545/htdocs/mypoject/admi‌​n/company.php?compan‌​y_id=92` ... just to confirm I have `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` in /.htaccess and `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` plus above rule with R in /admin/.htaccess file. I really thank you for all the help so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155008/discussion-between-anubhava-and-nonice).